# How to answer Yes and No question paramiko

Tags: python, output, paramiko

I need to save configuration on switch extreme. The command is :

> save configuration "File Name"

After of command's execution i need to answer 2 question.

First:

> Do you want to save configuration ? (y/N) -> I have to say Yes

Second:

> Do you want to make "File Name".cfg the default database? (y/N) -> I
>   have to say No

I am using paramiko for command execution.

Below is a piece of my code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('save configuration '+ backupFileName)
#Now i need to say first Yes and then NO
```

Someone could help me?

Thanks

Comment: I think you should add a little bit of context in your question : what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: Hi @JosephBudin i'm trying to achieve the file configuration

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(f'save configuration {backupFileName};yes;no')`

Comment: Post the output log?

Comment: The output is done with stdout.read() %% Unrecognized command: "save configuration p_10_1_5_30_04-11-2019_18_07_14;Yes;No"

Comment: Try this: `stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(f'save configuration {backupFileName};yes | reload;no |reload')`